# How do I create a bar graph in PHP using SQL data?

Tags: php, sql, database, graph, charts

I am trying to create a simple bar graph to display results of an athletic event (e.g. 100m race) I have already generated a **'Results' table** where the results of this event are displayed - but I want the user of the site to be able to click a *'view graph'* type button which will show these results in a (**horizontal**) bar chart.

What's the *easiest/simplest* way?

The following is what I have already on my '*viewesults3.php*' page:

```
            <?php
            session_start();
            require_once("connect.php");
            //require_once("restriction.php");
            ?>

                <html>
                    <body>
                        <div id="mainFrame">
                            <form id="results" method="get">
                                <table id="results" border="1" bordercolor="#FFCC66">
                                    <th bgcolor="#FFCC66">Result ID: </th>
                                    <th bgcolor="#FFCC66">Position: </th>
                                    <th bgcolor="#FFCC66">Time: </th>
                                    <th bgcolor="#FFCC66">Event ID: </th>       
                                    <th bgcolor="#FFCC66">Athlete ID: </th>

                                        <?php
                                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Results");
                                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                            {
                                                $rID = $row['rID'];
                                                $position = $row['position'];                                       
                                                $time = $row['time'];   
                                                $meID = $row['meID'];
                                                $atID = $row['atID'];               

                                                echo "<tr data-row='$rID'><td>$rID</td>";
                                                echo "<td>".$position."</td>";
                                                echo "<td>".$time."</td>";
                                                echo "<td>".$meID."</td>";
                                                echo "<td>".$atID."</td>";

                                                echo "</tr>";
                                            }
                                        ?>      
                                </table>
                            </form>
                        </div>          
                            <center>
                                    <div id="graphs" align="center">
                                    <a href=".php" class="button">Generate graph!</a>
                                    </div>
                            </center>
                    </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: Visit Google and enter *"How do I create a bar graph in PHP using SQL data?"* into the search box; you're guaranteed to get results. See **Related** >>> also. *"What's the easiest/simplest way?"* --- There's a simple way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

One easy way using plain sql is mysql's REPEAT function. You can repeat a character X times for whatever the result value is (round or truncate to remove fractions).

Here is an example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e2d7/1/0

In that example I repeat the pipe character ( | ) x times depending on the "score" value (adjust as needed).

You can also highlight the the pipe characters in your HTML, making each a solid bar.

Comment: Now this is a way cool fiddle. Will **+1**

Comment: That looks cool! Is there a way to add to this so that it will automatically generate the graph depending on the contents of the Results table already presented on the page?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but if you're saying you already have a query that brings back xyz and you want to put the graph on the same page, yes, just add this to your existing select statement to produce the graph. You might want to normalize it depending on how large your #s are, for instance if you were doing a graph with numbers in the millions, maybe divide by 1 million to express one character for each million.

Comment: Base yourself on the fiddle's query `select score, repeat('|',score) as graph from tbl` which does exactly that. @user3396375  `tbl` is "your" table name.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to know - I will try it. Thank you